# Insert values to a dictionary in an ascending order in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a a class that gets key and value and add them to a dictionary. I am trying to insert into the dict while keeping the order of the values in an ascending order. I know that OrderedDict remembers the order that keys were first inserted, but wondering what to use if I want to keep the values of the dict sorted as well. Here is an example:

```
rom collections import OrderedDict
from random import randint


class MyDict():
    def __init__(self):
        self.d=OrderedDict()

    def add(self, key, val):
        self.d[key] = val

    def show(self):
        return self.d

i=1
obj=MyDict()
for _ in range(5):
    obj.add(i, randint(1,50))
    i+=1

print(obj.show())
OrderedDict([(1, 8), (2, 6), (3, 10), (4, 32), (5, 15)])
```

However, I am looking to get something like this:

```
OrderedDict([(2, 6), (1, 8), (3, 10), (5, 15), (4, 32)])
```

Comment: Are you looking to keep the dict sorted after each insertion, or only after all insertions are done?

Comment: @blhsing preferably after each insertion.

Comment: @armin If so, does efficiency matter?

Comment: @armin Can you describe your use case?

Comment: @armin Since you want to sort after each insertion may be use [`heapq` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html).

Comment: @blhsing I edited the question and added more context.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA the max len of the dict is not exceeding 50.

Comment: @armin Your edited code still does not show why you need to keep the dict sorted after each insertion, since you output the dict only after all insertions are done.

Comment: @blhsing since I am creating multiple objects of class MyDict and I preferably don't want to sort each  dict individually. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is apparent from your comments that you only need the dict sorted upon output but not during a series of insertions, you don't actually need to incur the overhead of sorting upon each insertion, but rather you can add sorting to methods where the order matters, which can be done by subclassing `OrderedDict` and overriding all such methods with ones that would sort the items first.

The example below overrides the `__repr__` method just so that printing the object would produce your desired output, but you should override all the other relevant methods for completeness:

```
class MyDict(OrderedDict):
    def __sorted(self):
        sorted_items = sorted(super().items(), key=lambda t: t[::-1])
        self.clear()
        self.update(sorted_items)

    def __repr__(self):
        self.__sorted()
        return super().__repr__()

    # do the same to methods __str__, __iter__, items, keys, values, popitem, etc.
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/RudeMurkyIntegrationtesting

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking to sort the dictionary based on the values

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> from random import randint
>>> 
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> 
>>> i=1
>>> for _ in range(5):
...     d[i] = randint(1,50)
...     i+=1
... 
>>> 
>>> sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:(x[1],x[0]))
[(2, 2), (5, 20), (3, 35), (1, 36), (4, 47)]
>>>
```

`key` within sorted can be used in this case to sort based on values